# Docker diff isn't showing changes to new files

Tags: docker, diff

Let's say I create a new ubuntu image, and add a file to the container, like so:

`touch /file1`

I run `docker diff <container_id>`, and I see that `/file1` has been added to the system. Awesome. However, now when I do something like this:

`echo "hello" > /file1`

I do not see that change when I run docker diff again. However, if I create a file under say, `/etc`, `docker diff` will show that `/etc` has changed, and that `/etc/new_file` has been added (so I know docker diff can show changed files).

Does anyone know of a way to show changes to files that are added to the container during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/29328,

As in the post above, **docker diff** compares differences in the container's rootfs from the image.

The image will only know a file is added and will not have any concept of what happened inside the file.